# Proving the Lebesgue outer of a set is equal to its volume

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, volume

I want to prove the following statement

> if $A$ has volume, then
> $$
> \left( \operatorname{vol}(A) = \int_A \chi_A \right) = \inf\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \operatorname{vol}(S_i) \ | S_1, S_2,\cdots \text{is an open cover of $A$ by boxes} \right\}
> $$
> where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of $A$ and the volume of a set is the Riemann integral of its characteristic function. i.e. $\int_A \chi_A$. A set has volume simply means the Riemann integral exists.

My updated attempt. Let $S_1,S_2,\cdots$ be a countable cover of $A$. Since $vol(A) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^N vol(A_i)$ if $A_1,\cdots,A_N$ is a finite cover of $A$, by induction we can show that this is true for any countable cover of $A$. So $\sum_{i=1}^\infty vol(S_i) \geqslant vol(A)$.

Now, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Let $B$ be a box containing $A$. Since $vol(A) = \inf\{ U(\chi_A, P) \}$, where the infimum is taken over all partitions of $B$, there exists a partition $P$ of $B$ such that $U(\chi_A, P) < vol(A) + \epsilon$. Let $B_1P$ denote the collection of boxes that intersect $A$, then $B_1P$ covers $A$ and $U(\chi_A, P) =  \sum_{S \in B_1P} vol(S) < vol(A) + \epsilon$. Thus, $vol(A) = \inf \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty vol(S_i) | A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty S_i \right\}$

This time, I tried to prove $vol(A)$ is the infimum of all countable covers of $A$ by applying the property of infimum. Is my proof correct this time? Any comment is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I would like modify the first part of my proof. Let $S_1,S_2,\cdots$ be a countable cover of $A$. Since $A$ has volume and therefore $\partial A$ has measure zero, there exists $T_1,T_2,\cdots$ such that $\partial A \subset \bigcup_{i =1}^\infty T_i, \sum_{i = 1}^\infty v(T_i) < \epsilon$. Then $A \cup \partial A = \overline{A} \subset \left(\bigcup_{i =1}^\infty S_i \right) \cup \left(\bigcup_{i =1}^\infty T_i \right)$. $\overline{A}$ compact implies there exists a finite set $\{ S_1, \cdots, S_n, T_1, \cdots, T_m \} \subset \{S_1, S_2, \cdots, T_1, T_2, \cdots \}$ which covers $\overline{A}$. So
$$
vol(A) = vol(\overline{A}) \leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^n v(S_i) + \sum_{i = 1}^m v(T_i) < \sum_{i = 1}^\infty v(S_i) + \epsilon
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitary, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty vol(S_i) \geqslant vol(A)$.

Comment: I don't see how $vol(A) = \inf\{\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}vol(S_i) | A \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty}S_i\}$ follows from what you wrote. What follows is that the right hand side is less than or equal to the left hand side. Also, what are the $S_i$? Are they closed boxes, open balls, arbitrary sets with Riemann volume, or what?

Comment: I'm using the property that $p=\inf A$ if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$, there is an $x\in A$ with $x<p+\epsilon$, and $x\geq p$ for every $x\in A$. The $S_i$'s are open boxes (or balls). I will change that in the problem statement.

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics Oh I see, the second part of your proof looks correct, but the first doesn't. Induction can only extend that result to finite covers. It doesn't prove it for countable covers, especially since it might be that no finite subset of the countable cover covers $A$. To prove the first part, you can note that $U(\chi_A) = U(\chi_{\overline{A}})$, and that a countable cover of a compact set by open boxes reduces to a finite cover.

Comment: I see your point. I've changed the first part of my proof. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes it looks good now, but you should be explicit in mentioning that the $S_i$s and the $T_i$s are open boxes since that is necessary for obtaining a finite subcover of $A$.

Comment: I see. I will modify that. Thank you very much for your help!